# PHP Query Loading too slow. How to speed up?

Tags: php, mysql

Does anyone know a more efficient way to write the following.  my load time over a minute right now.  This what I came up with after an even longer codeset.

```
$max = $i + 25;
while ($i < $max)
  {
    $memberno = $memberid;
    if($pulledid!=$memberid)
      {
        $pulledid = mysql_result($result99,$i,"id_member");
        $sql_statement = "Select vinyl_fortrade.ImageID,vinyl_fortrade.MemberID from vinyl_fortrade where exists (Select ImageID from vinyl_wanted WHERE MemberID = $memberno AND vinyl_wanted.ImageID = vinyl_fortrade.ImageID) AND vinyl_fortrade.MemberID=$pulledid";
        $result=mysql_query($sql_statement)or die(mysql_error());    
        $num=mysql_numrows($result);
        if($num>0)
          {
            $sql_statement2 = "Select vinyl_wanted.ImageID, vinyl_wanted.MemberID from vinyl_wanted where exists (Select ImageID from vinyl_fortrade WHERE MemberID = $memberno AND vinyl_wanted.ImageID = vinyl_fortrade.ImageID) AND vinyl_wanted.MemberID=$pulledid";
            $result2=mysql_query($sql_statement2)or die(mysql_error());                
            $num2=mysql_numrows($result2);
            $membername = mysql_result($result99,$i,"smf_members.member_name");
            $userid2 = mysql_result($result99,$i,"smf_members.id_member");
            if ($num2 > 0)
              {
                $lastlogged = mysql_result($result99,$i,"smf_members.last_login");
                echo '<td><a href="http://vinylmationconnection.com/forum/index.php?action=pm;sa=send;    u='.$userid.'"style="color: #FFF">'.$membername.'</a><br>Last Logged In:<br>';
                echo date('Y-m-d', $lastlogged);
                echo ':</td>';
                echo '<td>';
                $n = 0;
                $m = 0;
                while ($n < $num)
                  {
                    $title=mysql_result($result,$n,"vinyl_fortrade.ImageID");
                    $sql_statementj = "Select * from vinyl_figures WHERE ImageID = '$title'";
                    $resultj=mysql_query($sql_statementj)or die(mysql_error());  
                    $seriess=mysql_result($resultj,0,"vinyl_figures.Series");
                    echo '<img  src="http://vinylmationconnection.com/images/p'.$seriess.'/'.$title.'.jpg">';
                    $n++;
                    if($n%4=="0")
                      echo "<br>";
                  }
                echo '</td><td>';
                while ($m < $num2)
                  {
                    $title=mysql_result($result2,$m,"vinyl_wanted.ImageID");
                    $sql_statementj = "Select Series from vinyl_figures WHERE ImageID = '$title'";
                    $resultj=mysql_query($sql_statementj)or die(mysql_error());  
                    $seriess=mysql_result($resultj,0,"vinyl_figures.Series");
                    echo '<img src="http://vinylmationconnection.com/images/p'.$seriess.'/'.$title.'.jpg">';
                    $m++;
                    if($m%4=="0")
                      echo "<br>";
                  }                              
                echo '</td> </tr>';
              }
          }
      }
    $i++;
  }
```

Please let me know if ths code is self explanatory.

Comment: Generally, the way you solve performance problems is to run a profiler on the code, and let the profiler tell you which part of the code is too slow.

Comment: This code couldn't be better self-explanatory... Remove that 2 while loops from within the main while loop. Join the queries to only have **ONE**. And I guess that the main `while` loop is running inside another `for` or `foreach` loop... Jesus, this is kinda time consumption, isn't it? And the queries in a `while` loops...Sorry, This **must** be running slow...

Comment: @moonwave99: It's entirely unnecessary to insult the poster.  Rather than saying "it is awful", explain how it can be improved.  If you can't do that, then say nothing.

Comment: Start using JOINs in your queries rather than nested queries - nesting is a major overhead

Comment: Well, there is simple not a single good practice used, and the best thing would be to start learning from scratch: no nested loops, no nested queries, no separation of concerns overall. This comes way *before* thinking about performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$sql_statementj = "Select * from vinyl_figures WHERE ImageID = '$title'";
$sql_statementj = "Select Series from vinyl_figures WHERE ImageID = '$title'";
```

in these 2 statements you seem to make a mysql request  for the same file if I got your code right. make these requests outside the loops, this should do some work.

Comment: Queries inside of loops are almost always a bad idea. Queries without proper escaping are *always* a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Write a stored procedure (maybe a simple query/View could be enough) to do all these query stuff and watch for database indexing.

Answer (score 0):

The WHERE EXISTS clause is almost certainly the culprit, and it should be refactored.  General guidelines for slow queries...

1. Use EXPLAIN SELECT to see what the query is really doing
2. Add indexes on all columns used in WHERE, JOIN, ORDER, GROUP
3. Avoid SELECT * and instead SELECT only the columns you need
4. Add LIMIT to all queries that do not require a complete table scan.

Answer (score 0):

Except for the answeres that are alredy mentined I could suggest you to use mod_deflate to compress the page before sending it to the browser and in should have some effect. Althrough if you are on local environment that also may cause a slow execution, becouse of the load on the machine.

And as well I think that you could lose the first while by using `LIMIT $i, 25`  in the query I think that it will have the same effect. To when you fetch them all with a simple foreach and it is done and I would suggest you to push as much as possible in a single query that will increse the load a bit but it should decrease the loading time.

I am not a 100% professional but am trying to be of help.